# Jira Query for hyphenated words

Tags: search, full-text-search, jira, wildcard

There are many words which can have a hyphen, a space or be a full word. For example:

- Wifi
- Wi-fi
- Wi fi

I am attempting to figure out if there is some kind of wildcard search that will allow me to capture all three as a result when I do a search in Jira. Using * search (for example, searching "wi*fi" returns either Wi-fi or Wi fi but wont return the full version Wifi

Is there a simple way I can get all three variants of Wifi to return using a simple wildcard search?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [Performing Text Searches](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performing+Text+Searches) documentation it says:

> JIRA does NOT support leading wildcards or Wildcards in phrases currently

However it later says:

> To perform a single character wildcard search use the "?" symbol.
>
> To perform a multiple character wildcard search use the "*" symbol.

So as to why your search is not working I am unsure.

However they do recommend installing the [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin which beefs up the JQL and allows you to use a regex:

```
issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("project = JRA", "description", "ABC\\d{4}")
```

Which may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to combine multiple searches here:
`(fieldname ~ "wi*fi" or fieldname ~ "wifi")` will return the desired results.